# digital circuits math

Tags: digital-logic

I want to study digital circuits with the book "digital design" by M Morris Mano.

and I have no math knowledge.(I know only + - * /)

Do I have to study math first? if so, how much?

Generally(not specific to that "digital design" book) in which year, does the subject need math? First or second year?

Comment: Engineering subjects rely on maths. There is no escape from maths.

Comment: Well.. do you want to risk stabbing yourself with a knife, or do you want to properly handle a knife like a ninja? Knife being a metaphor for electricity which can be fatal if handled poorly.

Comment: @MITURAJ - that's not really all that true.  Basic abstracted digital logic, while something that *can* be treated as a branch of mathematics, has next to no dependency on most ordinary *practical* math courses of the sort that non-math majors (including engineers) would be required to take.  However analog and RF circuit analysis *is* quite heavy on conventional mathematics, and of course there are places in the digital realm where the abstractions that let you often ignore the analog issues break down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How deep into digital circuit design are you trying to go?

If all you want to do is build simple logic functions that are not very robust, you pretty much don't need to know any math beyond basic arithmetic and logic.

If you want to design something more robust, and do something actually useful, you'll need to know things like linear algebra (matrices), or signal theory, or set theory etc.

Answer (score 3):

You should study logic and boolean algebra for beginning. Also you can look over logic gates. I wish it helps.

Comment: While these can be treated as a branch of mathematics they can also simply be approached on their own in an application-driven manner, without any other conventional math background.  Conventional math is primarily involved for the electrical issues where the digital abstraction breaks down, when analyzing performance, and for context in trying to understand the problems circuits might be computing solutions to.